# Kotlin : if String is null and double bang(!!) operator is used, why does it give compile error for length function?

Tags: kotlin, compiler-errors, string-length, non-nullable, kotlin-null-safety

example:

```
fun main(){
    var userInput: String?
    //userInput = null
    userInput = "asbdef"
    var inputLength:Int? = userInput!!.length
    println("Length of the string is :"+inputLength)
}
```

Output :
Length of the string is :6

```
fun main(){
    var userInput: String?
    userInput = null
    //userInput = "asbdef"
    var inputLength:Int? = userInput!!.length
    println("Length of the string is :"+inputLength)
}
```

Output :
Unresolved reference: length

I want to know why it gives compile error?

If I just replace (!!) operator with (?) it compiles well but prints output as null.

PS: I'm newbie in Kotlin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `?.` operator short-circuits if the left side evaluates to `null`. So the result of `nullVariable?.length` is `null` and `.length` is never evaluated. Your first example is effectively doing:

```
println("Length of the string is :" + null)
```

The `!!` operator says "throw a `NullPointerException` if the left side is null. Otherwise, we know it's not null on the right side". You can see this if you change your second example a little:

```
val userInput: String? = null
val inputLength:Int = userInput!!.length // throws NullPointerException
```

---

However, I'm not sure why are you are getting `Unresolved reference: length`. It looks like that the compiler is doing some optimization when you assign `null` directly to `userInput`, so rather than compiling it to a `String?` which throws an NPE at runtime, it knows the value is only `null` (not `String?`) at compile time, and therefore can't have the `length` property because `null` is not a reference.

You can force it to give you to `NullPointerException` by adding a layer of abstraction via a function call:

```
fun main(){
    var userInput: String? = "foo"
    userInput = alwaysNull()
    val inputLength:Int = userInput!!.length // NullPointerException
}

fun alwaysNull(): String? = null
```

I don't see anything n the [Null Safety](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html) documentation about the difference in behaviour between initializing in one line / via a function call vs. assigning `null` directly to a var though, so what's happening under the hood to get `Unresolved reference` is just a guess.